# Custom TableViews + CustomCell

Tags: swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-cell

This is probably a newbie mistake and question but what's wrong with this code below?

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var TitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var NumbersView: UILabel!




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func customInit(text: String, numbersText: String, photo: UIImage) {
        self.TitleLabel.text = text
        self.NumbersView.text = text
        self.ImageView.photo = UIImage)
    }


}
```

I'm following a tutorial called " SegmentedControl  - Switch 'Custom' TableViews: Swift 3" and the user used the following code: func customInit(text: String, accessoryText: String but I changed it to include an UIImage but I don't know if thats correct or needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
self.ImageView.image = photo
self.NumbersView.text = numbersText
```